# Error consumiendo un web service: no se puede ir automaticamente al servidor

Tags: c#, webservice, soap

Holas

Estoy consumiendo una web service SOAP para envío de los comprobantes de pago electrónico de SUNAT con la siguiente función:

```
public string EnviarDocumento(string FileZip)
    {
        try
        {
            FilePath = Path.Combine(pathHome, @"ENVIO\", FileZip);
            byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            wService.Open();

            returnByte = wService.sendBill(FileZip, byteArray, "");
            wService.Close();
            FileRpta = Path.Combine(pathHome, @"RPTA\R-", FileZip);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileRpta, FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(returnByte, 0, returnByte.Length);
            fs.Close();
            strRetorno = "Archivo generado con éxito!";
        }
        catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
        {
            strRetorno = ex.Code.Name;
            throw;
        }

        return strRetorno;
    }
```

Sin embargo en la siguiente función, al llamar el método sendBill me salta el error siguiente:

"No se puede ir automáticamente al servidor. Error de conexión con el servidor 'e-beta.sunat.gob.pe'. Parece que Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) no se está ejecutando en el equipo remoto. Consulte la Ayuda para obtener asistencia sobre la configuración de la depuración remota."

He verificado que la web service está activa y se encuentra referenciado a mi proyecto.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.